# After milvus is started, where is the newly inserted data stored?

Tags: database, vector, milvus

I follow this [link](https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/1.1/INSTALL.md#build-from-source) to start Milvus1.1.1.
After I started it successfully, I inserted some data into it.
But I don't know where my data is saved.

Answer (score 0):

For milvus1.1, the storage path is defined in server_config.yaml, `storage.path`, there should be like below block in configurations:

```
storage:
  path: /var/lib/milvus
```

So the default data storage location is /var/lib/milvus